# Import Libre Office Writer Document in Draw?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, drawing, libreoffice-draw

Is it possible to import a LibreOffice Writer Document with tables and pictures without layout modifications in LibreOffice Draw?

It seems I can't insert the whole file at once. When trying to copy and paste font size 12 becomes suddenly 18!

Comment: What might be the reason to import the Writer document from Draw?

Answer (score 0):

Try Menu `Insert` -> `Object` -> `OLE Object` -> `Create from file`. Optionally, you may *link* the odt file so changes in that file will appear in the odg file, too. Otherwise, the original file won't be affected by changes of the OLE object in draw.